# JPA - One to many merge issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am facing the next issue, when I trying to merge an entity.

I have a class Menu (One to Many) --> Category  (One to Many) --> Goods association.

If I persist first the menu with an empty List of Category and Goods the menu is persisted correctly.

Now, if I merge the current save menu with one category and empty List of Goods, the Category saves fine, even if I add a new good into the empty List of goods this is persisted fine.

Now, If I add a second good into the list of goods I have this error:

> Menu [menuId=1, menu_name=dsad, menu_description=null,
>   categories=[Category [category_id=1, categoryName=a, goods=[GoodsImp
>   [id=1, brand=asd, createdDate=Mon Jan 22 18:26:35 ART 2018], price
>   =3.0, description=asd, type= product] ], GoodsImp [id=null, brand=dsad, createdDate=null], price=33333.0, description=sd, type=
>   product] ]]], Category [category_id=2, categoryName=b, goods=[ ]]],
>   business=2]
>
> -------------- Hibernate:
>
> ```
> /* load models.menu.Menu */ select
>     menu0_.MENU_ID as MENU_ID1_7_1_,
>     menu0_.BUSINESS_ID as BUSINESS2_7_1_,
>     menu0_.MENU_DESCRIPTION as MENU_DES3_7_1_,
>     menu0_.MENU_NAME as MENU_NAM4_7_1_,
>     categories1_.Menu_MENU_ID as Menu_MEN1_8_3_,
>     category2_.CATEGORY_ID as categori2_8_3_,
>     category2_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY1_2_0_,
>     category2_.CATEGORY_NAME as CATEGORY2_2_0_
> from
>     MENUES menu0_
> left outer join
>     MENUES_CATEGORIES categories1_
>         on menu0_.MENU_ID=categories1_.Menu_MENU_ID
> left outer join
>     Categories category2_
>         on categories1_.categories_CATEGORY_ID=category2_.CATEGORY_ID
> where
>     menu0_.MENU_ID=? Hibernate:
> /* load models.menu.Product */ select
>     product0_.GOODS_ID as GOODS_ID2_6_0_,
>     product0_.GOODS_BRAND as GOODS_BR3_6_0_,
>     product0_.GOODS_CREATED as GOODS_CR4_6_0_,
>     product0_.GOODS_DESCRIPTION as GOODS_DE5_6_0_,
>     product0_.GOODS_IMAGE as GOODS_IM6_6_0_,
>     product0_.GOODS_PRICE as GOODS_PR7_6_0_
> from
>     GOODS product0_
> where
>     product0_.GOODS_ID=?
>     and product0_.DTYPE='PRODUCT'
> ```

Hibernate:

> ```
> /* insert models.menu.Product
>     */ insert
>     into
>         GOODS
>         (GOODS_BRAND, GOODS_CREATED, GOODS_DESCRIPTION, GOODS_IMAGE, GOODS_PRICE, DTYPE)
>     values
>         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'PRODUCT') Hibernate:
> select
>     goods0_.GOODS_ID as GOODS_ID2_6_0_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_ID as GOODS_ID2_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_BRAND as GOODS_BR3_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_CREATED as GOODS_CR4_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_DESCRIPTION as GOODS_DE5_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_IMAGE as GOODS_IM6_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_PRICE as GOODS_PR7_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_PRICE_TYPE as GOODS_PR8_6_1_,
>     goods0_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_6_1_
> from
>     GOODS goods0_
> where
>     goods0_.GOODS_ID=? Hibernate:
> select
>     goods0_.GOODS_ID as GOODS_ID2_6_0_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_ID as GOODS_ID2_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_BRAND as GOODS_BR3_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_CREATED as GOODS_CR4_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_DESCRIPTION as GOODS_DE5_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_IMAGE as GOODS_IM6_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_PRICE as GOODS_PR7_6_1_,
>     goods0_.GOODS_PRICE_TYPE as GOODS_PR8_6_1_,
>     goods0_.DTYPE as DTYPE1_6_1_
> from
>     GOODS goods0_
> where
>     goods0_.GOODS_ID=? Hibernate:
>
>
>
>    /* update  models.menu.Product */ update
>         GOODS
>     set
>         GOODS_BRAND=?,
>         GOODS_CREATED=?,
>         GOODS_DESCRIPTION=?,
>         GOODS_IMAGE=?,
>         GOODS_PRICE=?
>     where
>         GOODS_ID=? Hibernate:
> /* create one-to-many row models.menu.Category.goods */ update
>     GOODS
> set
>     GOODS_ID=?
> where
>     GOODS_ID=? [warn] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000 [error] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate
> ```
>
> entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' [error] application -
>
> ! @76lfn933p - Internal server error, for (PUT) [/menu] ->
>
> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement]]
>           at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
>           at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:182)
>           at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:155)
>           at play.filters.cors.AbstractCORSPolicy$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(AbstractCORSPolicy.scala:153)
>           at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:412)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
>           at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement
>           at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1443)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1423)
>           at repository.JPAMenuesRepository.lambda$updateMenu$2(JPAMenuesRepository.java:46)
>           at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.lambda$withTransaction$3(DefaultJPAApi.java:197)
>           at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:138)
>           at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:196)
>           at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:169)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
>   not execute statement
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.insertRows(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1567)
>           at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.insertRows(OneToManyPersister.java:193)
>           at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:85)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
>   Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)

Comment: `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'  ` You need to be sure that the second object don`t is a duplicate. What is the way that the Identifier are be generated?

Comment: The goods object generate the ID by the Identity generation type: 
 `@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it.

The problem was, that the relation One to Many has a @JoinColumn instead of @JoinTable. Thats the issue when you code for several hours, you just dont see the obvious.

Thanks to all.

Comment: A good exercise is try to post all core code in a question. Normally you will find the error while writing the question. And you will not need to create a question